# Table Format in email body using Python Exchangelib library

Tags: python, exchangelib

I am exploring in python to write email using [exchangelib](/questions/tagged/exchangelib) library with body content which contains a table content.

I have tried the code to add table in the body content.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    from exchangelib import Account, Credentials, Message, Mailbox
    dfReport = pd.read_excel("test.xlsx")
    FilteredData = dfReport[dfReport["ColumnID"].str.contains('MyCharacter')]
    DataTable = pd.pivot_table(FilteredData ,index="Processor",values="TicketID",aggfunc=np.count_nonzero,margins=True)

    EmailAdd = 'XXX@YYY.Z'
    EmailPass = 'XXXXXX'
    MyAccount = Account(EmailAdd,credentials=Credentials(EmailAdd,EmailPass),autodiscover=True)

    MyMessage = Message(account=MyAccount, folder=MyAccount.sent,subject='Daily motivation', body=DataTable, to_recipients=[Mailbox(email_address='AAA@BBB.CC')])

    MyMessage.send_and_save()
```

below demonstration is expected in message body:

```
    Name    Count
    Item 1  53
    Item 2  38
    Item 3  123
    Item 4  175
    Item 5  212
```

but in outlook exchange email looks like this:

```
    Name
    Count
    Item 1         53
    Item 2                38
    Item 3     123
    Item 4    175
    Item 4            212
```

Comment: What is `DenizTbl`? Your code doesn't compile.

Comment: for better demonstration, I changed some definition in my question but DenizTbl missed. it is DataTable. it edited my question. thanks for your consideration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To properly control the format of your email body, you need to send the body as HTML.

The easiest is probably to convert the dataframe to a string, encapsulate it in `<pre>` tags and define a mono-spaced font.

You can read up on creating emails with an HTML body at https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib#creating-updating-deleting-sending-and-moving

Comment: I tried your advise and it was worked for manually typed table by HTML Codes. can you guide me how can I changed  extracted `DataTable` from `"test.xlsx"` to HTML code ?

Comment: here is the manually written table code:

        `body=HTMLBody('<style>table, th, td {  border: 1px solid black;}</style><table> <tr><th>Firstname</th><th>Lastname</th> <th>Age</th></tr><tr><td>Jill</td><td>Smith</td> <td>50</td></tr><tr><td>Eve</td><td>Jackson</td> <td>94</td></tr></table>')`

Comment: Pandas apparently has a `.to_html()` method you can use: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html

Comment: Thanks for you valuable support. I used `DataHtml = pd.DataFrame.to_html(DataTable )` for changing table data into html code then use it `body = HTMLBody(DataHtml)` for exchange body